# .BAT script not running via Task Scheduler

Tags: batch-file, cmd, imagemagick, windows-task-scheduler

I have an ImageMagick script in `.bat` format and have scheduled it via task scheduler to run under administrator.

The `.bat` works perfectly when running it normally, but Task Scheduler won't run it at all.

Anyone know why?

Script paste is below:

```
"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.1.0-Q16-HDRI\magick.exe" H:\PD_IMAGES_BOXI\*.jpg ^
-set filename:name "%%t" ^
( -clone 0--1 -resize 400x400 -gravity center -background white -extent 400x400 +write "//termsvr3/d$/Program Files (x86)/SAP BusinessObjects/SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0/images/400-%%[filename:name].jpg" ) ^
( -clone 0--1 -resize 200x200 -gravity center -background white -extent 200x200 +write "//termsvr3/d$/Program Files (x86)/SAP BusinessObjects/SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0/images/200-%%[filename:name].jpg" ) ^
( -clone 0--1 -resize 100x100 -gravity center -background white -extent 100x100 +write "//termsvr3/d$/Program Files (x86)/SAP BusinessObjects/SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0/images/100-%%[filename:name].jpg" ) ^
null:
del "H:\PD_IMAGES_BOXI\*.jpg"
```

Comment: What is `H:`? You need to ensure that `H:` is mapped and available to the 'administator', at the exact time the code is being run. That user would also require to have sufficient permissions to access that location too. As you didn't provide us with any information about your scheduled task, I can only guess that you are likely running this script before the user has logged in, and therefore before the `H:` drive/volume is mapped or available to them.

Comment: The H: drive is a location on one of our File Servers. The H: drive is mapped and available, and the Administrator account here has access to it. The script works outside of Task Scheduler normally with this same Administrator account.

Comment: Please post the configuration of your scheduled task. You should be able to do that from the command line using the appropriate options e.g. ```%SystemRoot%\System32\schtasks.exe /Query [/S system [/U username [/P [password]]]] /TN taskname [/V] /XML```

Comment: The administrator account in question has both local and domain admin though.

Comment: Please post the output from the command I gave you in my previous comment if you want further assistance. Your issue is clearly not the batch file, because you've told us it works directly when invoked by that account. The problem is therefore with the configuration of the Scheduled Task, and to fix that we will need to see it.

Comment: I managed to figure this one out. 
If you change the script file location or the time in the Scheduled Task, it seems to default back to the Local Administrator account rather than the Domain Admin account it was previously set to use. This is something I had overlooked. Changing it back now works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure this one out. If you change the script file location or the time in the Scheduled Task menu, it seems to default back to the Local Administrator account rather than the Domain Admin account it was previously set to use. This is something I had overlooked. Changing it back now works perfectly with the file location changes & the double wild cards.